# How to determine the Range of this ln() function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$f(x)=\ln \left|\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right|$$

I am told the range of f(x) is:
$f(x)\le \ln\frac{1}{2}=-\ln2$
but don't know how to get there.

I do know $f(x)$ becomes a piecewise function b/c of the absolute value based on $x>0$ and $x<0$
(Undefined at $x=0$)  I also know that the domain of any $\ln(f(x))$ is that $f(x)\gt0$.  I'm just not sure how to get the range.

Comment: First find the range of $\left|x/(1+x^2)\right|$, then use this to find the range of $f(x)$.

Comment: OK, but I haven't found the range of a function in some time.  Can you point me in the right direction?  Domain is all Reals.  So, is range all reals also?  With the || added, range is y>=0.   So range of ln|| would be ???

Comment: To simplify your life, you can remark that $|\frac{x}{1+x^2}|$ is an even function, so you can study it for $x>0$. On $(0,\infty)$, we have $|\frac{x}{1+x^2}|=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: No, Jack, the range is not all reals also.  Remember, the *range* of a function is the set of all of its possible outputs.  Take a look at this plot, where the function $|x/(1+x^2)|$ is drawn in blue.  The red lines are the boundary of its range.  No matter what the $x$ value is, $|x/(1+x^2)|$ will always be between the top red line and the bottom red line.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/AUKtH.png  Now, where are the red lines?  From the graph it sure looks like they're at $0$ and $1/2$, but how do you know for certain?

Comment: Antonio, I need to do this without a graphing utility.

Comment: @JackOfAll, of course, hence the last sentence in my comment.  By the way, to make sure someone gets a notification of a comment, put an @ before their name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Antonio Vargas said, it will help to first find the range of $M = |\frac x {1 + x^2}|$.

Since an absolute value is never negative, if $M$ can be zero then zero is the minimum.  I believe you can find the value of $x$ for which $M$ is zero.

Now we need to find out the maximum.  How large can $M$ get?  Notice that the denominator is "bigger" than the numerator, so for large values of $x$, $M$ approaches zero.  That is:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} M = 0$$

So somewhere before $x = \infty$, $M$ has a maximum value.  Since you tagged this as calculus you probably know to take a derivative to find a max:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x}{1 + x^2} = \frac{(1 - x)(1 + x)}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2} = 0$$

So your max will occur at $x=1$ or $x=-1$.  Now can you find the range of $M$, and thus the range of $\ln M$?

Comment: This was a big help. Thanks!

Comment: What about the minumum value of the range?   Are we assuming the lower end of the range is simply 0 b/c of the ln()?

Comment: Can you figure out what the smallest value M can be is?

Comment: No, that's not clear.  I know if you have log(x) then x>0 since x is the results of an exponent operation.  Otherwise, there are no critical points that are mins.  And it's even.  And the lim x-> infinity is 0.  Doesn't this all point to the lowest value being y=0?   Clearly, that's not right.

Comment: You need to first figure out what the smallest value of $M$ can be.  $M$ does not have a log function.

Comment: The smallest M can be is ..... Well, it goes through (0,0), so right after that (x->0+) you will have a very small value.  Also the limit as x-> infinity = 0, so the smallest it can be is 0.  However, on the negative side, M can have a negative value.  Do I need to take the derivative and find the exact minimum for M?  Or not bother b.c we are taking |M|, so the lowest |M| can ever be is 0.   Am I on the right track?   Then I need to evaluate the lowest value of ln|M|, which I don't know how to do either.

Comment: Yes.  The minimum of |M| is zero, by example and by constraint of absolute value.  Now see what you get when $$\lim_{M \rightarrow 0} \ln M$$.  Try using a calculator to find $\ln 0.1$, $\ln 0.01$, $\ln 0.001$, etc, and see if you see where this is going.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That limit seems to be negative infinity.  Hence the range being $y < -ln2$.  Thanks for sticking with it!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it.
Here is how I did it:

[image]

Comment: Well done, I'll point out that the statements $y \le -\ln 2$ and "the maximum value of $y$ is $-\ln 2$" are not exactly the same.  Now you just need to find a lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** By AM-GM, $\dfrac{1+x^2}2 \ge \lvert x \rvert$.

Comment: What is AM-GM ?

Comment: Arithmetic mean - Geometric mean